# How to fetch current locale in view in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am making a bilingual app. I am using same routes for each but I am using different views for both languages. Whenever I want to redirect to a route I want to pass `{{ route('test.route', 'en') }}`. Where I am passing `en`, I want to fetch the current locale value from the view and then pass it to the route. Please help.

Comment: You will have to get the get a value for 'en' (why not consider a session variable) then you can do something like:

`code`
{{ route('test.route', ['route'=>$variable_holding_route_value]) }}

Answer (score 67, accepted):

try this. It will give the locale set in your application

```
Config::get('app.locale')
```

Edit:

To use this in blade, use like the following, to echo your current locale in blade.

```
{{ Config::get('app.locale') }}
```

If you want to do a if condition in blade around it, it will become,

```
   @if ( Config::get('app.locale') == 'en')

   {{ 'Current Language is English' }}

   @elseif ( Config::get('app.locale') == 'ru' )

   {{ 'Current Language is Russian' }}

   @endif
```

To get current locale,

```
app()->getLocale()
```

Comment: in the blade?
Can I use it like `@if (Config::get('app.locale'))`?

Comment: In your blade template you can use it like this `{{ Config::get('app.locale') }}`

Comment: @FahadIqbalAhmadKhan `app.locale` will always be set to *something* so an `@if` won't be very useful. It'll always be true.

Comment: This will fetch config locale which could be different from current locale. To fetch current locale you should use `App::getLocale()` or `App::isLocale('...')`. [Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#introduction). You can also use `app()->getLocale()` which in Blade would be `{{ app()->getLocale() }}`.

Answer (score 5):

At first create a locale route and controller  :

```
Route::get('/locale/{lang}', 'LocaleController@setLocale')->name('locale');

class LocaleController extends Controller
{
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($locale, Config::get('languages'))) 
        {
            Session::put('app_locale', $locale);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Now you can check easily in every page:

```
  $locale = app()->getLocale();
  $version = $locale == 'en' ? $locale . 'English' : 'Bangla';
```